# Nginx-Ingress Controller (Domain url not working with out nodePort)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

domain URL is not funtional without nodePort, service type is configured as LoadBalancer but only accessible through nodePort. Looking forwar to see some solutions if possible.
[image]

manually configured the ingress but issue still persists.

Comment: You need to update your question to specify how was your cluster created, show the service yaml. Without it it will be hard to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.